# How to adapt this Philosophy.SE question to fit CV on-topic standards?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, migration

I asked this question on Philosophy Stack Exchange: [Epistemic value of multiple eyewitness accounts: single event vs. multiple events given a fixed number of eyewitnesses?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/93007/48437)

> Intuitively speaking, multiple independent eyewitness accounts of a
> single event are more convincing than a single eyewitness account. For
> example, multiple independent eyewitness accounts of a loud explosion
> in a remote area (e.g. from different locations and viewpoints) are
> more convincing/reliable than a single account (e.g. maybe the single
> witness hallucinated the explosion).
>
> A bit more formally, if we define X as some truth claim about some
> event, process or phenomenon in the real world, we could say that:
>
> P(X is true | multiple eyewitness accounts) > P(X is true | a single
> eyewitness account)
>
> However, what happens if we keep the number of eyewitness accounts
> constant and only change the number of events?
>
> For example, let X = "alien abductions are real", and let
> E<sub>i</sub> be a concrete example of an (alleged) alien abduction. X
> is a general claim, E<sub>i</sub> is a claim about a very specific
> instance of X. It is clear that E<sub>i</sub> entails X. Thus, which
> of the following probabilities is greater than the others?
>
> - P(E<sub>1</sub> is true | N eyewitness accounts for E<sub>1</sub>)
> - P(E<sub>1</sub> is true or E<sub>2</sub> is true or ... or E<sub>N</sub> is true | one eyewitness account for E<sub>i</sub>, for
>   each i in {1, ..., N})
> - P(E<sub>1</sub> is true or E<sub>2</sub> is true or ... or E<sub>N/2</sub>  is true | two eyewitness accounts for E<sub>i</sub>,
>   for each i in {1, ..., N/2})
> - P(E<sub>1</sub> is true  or E<sub>2</sub> is true or ... or E<sub>N/3</sub> is true | three eyewitness accounts for E<sub>i</sub>,
>   for each i in {1, ..., N/3})
> - Etc.
>
> In other words, given N eyewitness accounts, what is the optimal
> distribution of eyewitnesses over specific alleged instances of X that
> maximizes the probability of X being true? What should be more
> convincing, 1000 eyewitness accounts for E<sub>1</sub>, 500 eyewitness
> accounts for E<sub>1</sub> + 500 eyewitness accounts for
> E<sub>2</sub>, etc.?
>
> **Note**: I used eyewitness reports of abductions by aliens as an illustrative example, but the reasoning can be extended to other rare
> events, such as reports of miracles, paranormal phenomena, angelic
> encounters, Bigfoot sightings, testimonials from whistleblowers
> (conspiracy theories), etc.

I received the following suggestions in the comments:

> **Interesting question, but probably would get better answers on math.stackexchange.com or statistics.stackexchange.com !** If a witness claims they have seen event E_1, they might be lying or hallucinating, or someone else might have staged E_1. So you have to account for P(E_1 | eyewitness account), but also for P(X | E_1), which is the probability that aliens exist knowing that a possibly-staged alien abduction event happened.

> **You may get better answers on Cross Validated**. Under some simplifying assumptions (like equal credibility of reports, independent events, etc.), this is essentially a mathematical question about calculating Bayesian posteriors. The formula for multiple reports of a single event is standard, but I am not sure how they are calculated for derivative statements implied by multiple reported events. You may want to use a less provocative example than alien abductions there, so it doesn't become a distraction.

**Question**: How can I adapt this question to fit CV on-topic standards?

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that it is now cross-posted on two SE sites, which is discouraged and usually leads to one of the posts being closed. From the help: "*Please note, however, that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated.*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it’s fine to post as it is, and I look forward to reading replies.

Comment: [Question asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/585954/365786).